# Looping a vector of 5*n entries by steps of 5 while assigning chunks of 5 to local variables

Tags: iteration, vector

A server sends a vector of integers like
`[6 4 8 7 16 ...]` and the protocol says it will be always 5n values. Is there a nice way to loop over the vector assigning chunks of 5 values to 5 local variables? Even better if it works in case the 5n guarantee is not fulfilled, like setting the missing values to `nil` or a default. Paraphrasing what I have once `data` is the vector:

```lisp
(while (< i n-items)
  (let ((hokey (aref data i))
        (pokey (aref data (+ i 1)))
        ...)
    ...
    (setq i (+ i 5))))
```

Maybe something like this is possible?

```
(for (hokey pokey didly doby doo) data
  body
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *macro* may help:

```lisp
(defmacro for-5n-vec (loop-vars 5n-vec &rest body)
  `(mapc (apply-partially #'apply
                          (lambda (&optional ,@loop-vars)
                            ,@body))
         (seq-split (mapcar #'identity ,5n-vec) 5)))
```

For example,

```lisp
(for-5n-vec (a b c d e) [:6 'four 8 7.0 (16) "42"]
  (insert (format "\n%s %s %s %s %s\n"
                  a b c d e)))
```